# Remove redundant permissions from App info

Tags: android, android-permissions

Guess I have redundant permissions for my app in Apps → App info → Permissions: Phone and Storage. Indeed, previously in the Manifest were declared following permissions: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_PHONE_STATE`. But when I have removed this permissions I still can see according options in App info page, even after reinstall of the app. So how can I remove this options?

Comment: it may come from used libraries https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: @Selvin this helps me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This may occur because of Module project that you may be using in your project, i have experienced same problem by removing permissions from other module project